# Pass a parameter to a jquery callback, but use callback externally as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

According to various posts on SO and [this groovy example](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/06/passing-parameters-to-jquery-event.html) you can pass parameters to a jQuery callback function inside a JSON object like so:

```
$("myButton").on("click",{foo:"bar"},runStuff);
```

This works cool, but what if I also need `runStuff` to work with a normal context? I'm struggling with this:

Lets say my callback is a function that just prints it's parameter:

```
function printParam(param)
{
    console.log(param);
}
```

and this function should be called normally like this: `printParam("Hey!");` but also by an event:

```
$("body").on("DOMNodeInserted",{foo: "Hey!"},printParam);
```

I've tried to implement `printParam` like this:

```
function printParam(param)
{
    param = (event.data.foo) ? event.data.foo : param;
    console.log(param);
}
```

But of course this doesn't work, as `event` is undefined. What are my options here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `data` parameter of `.on()`, the data isn't passed directy to the callback, but in the `data` property of the Event object which is passed to the function.

Example:

```
$("myButton").on("click",{foo:"bar"},runStuff);
function runStuff(event) {
  console.log(event.data.foo);
}
```

So you could call `runStuff` with:

```
runStuff({data: {foo:"bar"}});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want.

```
function printParam(param)
{
    param = (param.data) ? param.data.foo : param;
    console.log(param);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ths;

```
 function printParam(param)
{
    param1 = (param.data.foo) ? param.data.foo : '';
    console.log(param1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Messing with it some more, I got this to work:

```
function printParam(event,data) //function to be called normally and as event callback
{
    if (event){
        data = (event.data.foo) ? event.data.foo : data;
    }
    console.log("%O",data);
}
```

Than `printParam()` can be invoked this way:

```
printParam(false,"bar");
```

Fiddled with it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5L2S5/).